# Can anyone explain convergence of parallel rays on the focus of a parabolic reflector using Fermat's Principle?

Tags: optics, refraction, variational-principle, optimization

Can anyone explain convergence of parallel rays on the focus of a parabolic reflector using Fermat's Principle? using optimization techniques from calculus?

Comment: This problem can easily be solved by using the law of reflection which is derived from Fermat's Principle:  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Fermat.html